# Is there a way to pass strings like this in C?

Tags: c, string, function, parameter-passing

I have a function which accepts a character array (ie, string) as argument.

But an integer variable's value should also be printed as part of string.

For example,
If I have a function like this:

```
int var=10;
void printStr(char str[])
{
   printf("%s", str);
}
```

and I need to print the value of integer variable 'var' with a message

> "The value of var is %d", var

I tried this

```
printStr( ("The value of var is %d", var) );
```

but it didn't work.

Is there a way to accomplish this without passing the variable as argument to `printStr()`?

The output in this case should be

> The value of var is 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you need the function `sprintf`/`snprintf` for generation of the string.

Try something like this:

```
char tempStr[30];
snprintf(tempStr, sizeof(tempStr), "The value of var is %d", var);
printStr(tempStr);
```

Is it what you need?

Comment: @Ilya That's a good one. But is there a way to do this without creating a string just for the sake of passing it to the function?

Comment: @J...S If it is allowed to have only one argument (a string), we need to build a string. If you can change something here (for instance, if you can use a `struct` containing both values: string and int), you will do it without `sprintf`/`snprintf`.

Comment: @J...S No, string formatting is strictly done by calling a function, there's no operator to do it in the language like in e.g. Python.

Comment: @J...S There is, but then you're basically implementing printf.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might find [variable number of arguments to functions](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html) and the [GCC format attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) useful to building your thing. You'll need to be using GCC for the attributes however, and not have any plans of being portable to other compilers.

I would not mess with these things however, and figure out a way to do things without this.

Comment: But the GCC format attributes aren't portable in respect with other compilers and the question hasn't a GCC tag, has it?

Comment: @harper the GCC format attributes are useful for type checking, but they're not crucial. I'll edit the thing and say it's applicabcle for GCC only.